# Unordered List Items not aligning in center properly?

Tags: css, html

I have 2 items in a  in HTML5 and I am trying to centrality(horizontal) align them. However the margin: 0 auto; isnt working nor can i think of anything else?

**HTML5 Code**

```
<section class="fourth">  

<div id="Top"> Top </div>


    <ul class="topUL" > 


    <li class="topthings"> List 1 </li>
    <li class="topthings"> List 2 </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

Because the methods i tried didnt work so i deleted them from the code this is really a simple CSS code.

```
.fourth {
height: 35em;
width: 100%;

/** STYLE **/
background-color: #0099FF;
}

#Top {

height:auto;
width:inherit;
text-align:center;

/** FONT STYLE **/

font-family: 'Wire One', Gadget, sans-serif;
color: White;
font-size: 150px;
}

.topthings {

display: inline-block;
margin: auto;

/**FONT STYLE**/
font-family: 'Tulpen One', Gadget, sans-serif;
color: White;
font-size: 75px;
}
```

Link to how it looks right now.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B27I0PqG2ru9eTByOTJsbTd2c1U/edit?usp=sharing

I want 'List 1' and 'List 2' to be equally aligned under the word "Top"

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but have you tried simply adding `text-align: center` to `.fourth` class?

```
.fourth {
height: 35em;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W92Q5/

Answer (score 0):

Add to your stylesheet:

```
.topUl { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

add one more css rule for UL tag

```
.topUL{display:block;text-align:center;}
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/2w34K/1/